# setonclicklistener not working on button click

Tags: android, onclicklistener

when i click on button it's shwoing error of null.
I don't know why stack overflow saying that this question agains the policy.

Mainactivity code

```
            Button bnt = findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
            bnt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

            {

                WebView web1;
                EditText editText = findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
                    public void onClick(final View view) {

                       String  Address = "http://" + editText.getText().toString();
                        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

                        WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                        webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        web1.loadUrl(Address);

                    }


            });

        }
```

XML Code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/go" />



<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" />
```

My errors are

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is against site policy to debug for someone .https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising your edittext and button in wrong way. You need to remove android prefix from their id

```
EditText editText = findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
```

should be

```
 EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit);
```

and this

```
Button bnt = findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

should be

```
Button bnt = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```